# How to unitest a call to IUIVisualizerService has been made

Tags: catel

I am trying to verify that a call to `IUiVisualizerService.ShowAsync(dialog)` has been made. I am using machine specifications as my testing framework with FakeItEasy. Any insight would be helpful.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In previous versions of Catel, it was shipped with a test implementation of the services (such as `IUIVisualizerService`), but due to low usage it has been removed. You could try to copy that implementation, or you could simply mock the service and return the expected call (in the end, that's all you need to do).